# How to recover RSA key due to phone replacement?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to develop an Android app using RSA to encrypt data. However, in the case of phone lost, how can I recover the RSA key pairs to the new phone to work on the encrypted data? Is there any mean I can re-generate the same RSA key pairs in the new phone?

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, could you find it useful by accepting?

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you need to implement an export option. You can also encrypt the private key which is generated from a password as in OpenSSL.

There is no way to re-generate if the RSA-keygen is random and it must be random. Otherwise, it will be insecure since we assume that the attacker knows your keygen method, too.

It seems that you store the encrypted data somewhere that can be recovered. You can store the encrypted private key there, too.

Keep in mind that, RSA is not for encryption. It will be very slow. For file encryption, you need a good password and a key generation algorithm like PBKDF2 and Argon2. So you only need to remember your password to decrypt. Then, you can use AES-GCM with the generated key. AES-GCM provides the Confidentiality, Integrity, and Authentication.

A good practice is using a well-established format as [OpenPGP message format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) which also supports password-based key encryption. In this way, you don't need to roll your own cryptography and you shouldn't. using the format will prevent you from your own design errors. The bonus of this format, one can use the external tools for decryption.